# Newline remains after doing shellescape() on a filename

Tags: filenames

I am working with a kind of database file containing filenames and some metadata:

```
2020-21-03        /run/My Drive/Folder 1/image1.jpg
2020-20-03        /run/My Drive/Folder 1/image2.jpg
```

I am aware that the `gf` keybind properly shellescapes `<cfile>` during a visual selection, allowing the highlighted file to be opened in the buffer.

How can I achieve a similar behaviour for any system command?

e.g. `feh '/run/My Drive/Folder 1/image1.jpg'`

I've had some success with `:execute '!feh ' . shellescape(@", 1)` (after yanking from the first `/` to the end of the line), but this passes a newline to the shell for some reason, causing the command to fail.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! One thought would be to create the commands in the buffer and then pipe that to a shell or xargs for execution; would that be acceptable?

Comment: I suppose you could actually replace each line with a shellescape version 

Comment: I've just done some tinkering with :execute, thanks. How does one get rid of newlines? shellescape with argument 1 didn't seem to be able to do that.

Comment: Never mind, I think I managed to fix the shellescape issue somehow. Guess I'll write what I did in the OP...

Comment: if you have a solution, it belongs in an answer. I’ve rolled back your edit (but you’ll still be able to find the text in the history if you want to copy/paste it into an answer).